# I'm new in firebase and I'm trying to get id document for parent collection but I can't figure it out

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have collection (Categories) and subcollection (product) and I try to delete the document in subcollection with id so I need id for Parent document how to get it?

```
cross.addEventListener('click',(e) => {
    e.stopPropagation();
    let id =e.target.parentElement.getAttribute('data-id');

    db.collection("Categories").doc("parent.id").collection("Product").doc(id).delete();
    })

    });

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot know the parent information unless you have the snapshot/reference of the document/sub-collection under the parent whose id you need.
The snapshots have a property 'parent' just like 'id'.

```
SubCollectionReference = DocumentSnapshot.ref.parent;
```

You can just use parent.parent to find out the document hosting the sub-collection.

```
ParentDocumentReference = DocumentSnapshot.ref.parent.parent;
```

If you just know the document id but do not have a snapshot or reference to the document, I suggest you to create a reference field to this document or just the parent document directly where ever you are pulling this id information from.